# How to find a node given the exact HTML tag as a string (using Nokogiri)?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

**Question**

I need to search a given web page for a particular node when given the exact HTML as a string. For instance, if given:

```
url = "https://www.wikipedia.org/"
node_to_find = "<title>Wikipedia</title>"
```

I want to "select" the  node on the page (and eventually return its children and sibling nodes). I'm having trouble with the Nokogiri docs, and how to exactly go about this. It seems as though, most of the time, people want to use Xpath syntax or the #css method to find nodes that satisfy a set of conditions. I want to use the HTML syntax and just find the exact match within a webpage.

---

**Possible start of a solution?**

If I create two Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment objects, they look similar but do not match due to the memory id being different. I think this might be a precursor to solving it?

```
irb(main):018:0> n = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<title>Wikipedia</title>").child

=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x47e7e4 name="title" children=[ <Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x47e08c "Wikipedia">]>

irb(main):019:0> n.class

=> Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

Then I create a second one using the exact same arguments. Compare them - it returns false:

```
irb(main):020:0> x = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<title>Wikipedia</title>").child 

=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x472958 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4724a8 "Wikipedia">]>

irb(main):021:0> n == x

=> false
```

So I'm thinking that if I can somehow create a method that can find matches like this, then I can perform operations of that node. In particular - I want to find the descendents (children and next sibling).

**EDIT**: I should mention that I have a method in my code that creates a Nokogiri::HTML::Document object from a given URL. So - that will be available to compare with.

```
class Page
attr_accessor :url, :node, :doc, :root

def initialize(params = {})
  @url = params.fetch(:url, "").to_s
  @node = params.fetch(:node, "").to_s
  @doc = parse_html(@url)
end

def parse_html(url)
  Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)  
end
```

end

Comment: You could traverse it: `document.traverse { |x| match = x if x.to_s == node_to_find }`

Comment: What's your question? How do you do it? Perhaps, if you understood better how to use CSS and XPath, you wouldn't want to do this? In particular, knowing CSS selectors is very useful when dealing with CSS and JavaScript, which are pretty much mandatory skills if you work with internet technologies these days. So those piggyback on each other.

Comment: #traverse would work even though the id's are unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by commenter @August, you could use [`Node#traverse`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#traverse-instance_method) to see if the string representation of any node matches the string form of your target node.

```ruby
def find_node(html_document, html_fragment)
  matching_node = nil
  html_document.traverse do |node|
    matching_node = node if node.to_s == html_fragment.to_s
  end
  matching_node
end
```

Of course, this approach is fraught with problems that boil down to the *canonical representation* of the data (do you care about attribute ordering? specific syntax items like quotation marks?  whitespace?).

**[Edit]** Here's a prototype of converting an arbitrary HTML element to an XPath expression.  It needs some work but the basic idea (match any element with the node name, specific attributes, and possibly text child) should be a good starting place.

```
def html_to_xpath(html_string)
  node = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(html_string).children.first
  has_more_than_one_child = (node.children.size > 1)
  has_non_text_child = node.children.any? { |x| x.type != Nokogiri::XML::Node::TEXT_NODE }
  if has_more_than_one_child || has_non_text_child
    raise ArgumentError.new('element may only have a single text child')
  end
  xpath = "//#{node.name}"
  node.attributes.each do |_, attr|
    xpath += "[#{attr.name}='#{attr.value}']" # TODO: escaping.
  end
  xpath += "[text()='#{node.children.first.to_s}']" unless node.children.empty?
  xpath
end
html_to_xpath('<title>Wikipedia</title>') # => "//title[text()='Wikipedia']"
html_to_xpath('<div id="foo">Foo</div>')  # => "//div[id='foo'][text()='Foo']"
html_to_xpath('<div><br/></div>') # => ArgumentError: element may only have a single text child
```

It seems possible that you could build an XPath from *any* HTML fragment (e.g. not restricted to those with only a single text child, per my prototype above) but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: I wish I had enough SO points to upvote you! As for your question, I only care about being able to count the total # of descendent nodes. Would that be possible using your solution? I'm sure it is with XML format (am currently trying to work that solution out now).

Comment: @DrewB: yes, you could use the `traverse` method again, on the matching node, to simply update a counter with each invocation.  Note that depending on exactly what you want to count (elements, nodes, etc) then you might want to check the node "type" as a predicate.

Comment: Are you aware of a gem that can convert HTML to xpath? I have a method that someone helped me with, but if there were some standard by which devs go about doing this - it may be better.

Comment: @DrewB: nope, I don't know of any such gem.  It shouldn't be a terribly difficult thing to achieve, again depending on specifics.  I'll update my answer with some thoughts.